# php string escaping like python's """ """?

Tags: php, escaping

Hi I was wondering if there is an easy way to escape strings in php.

In python I use """ """, and everything between there is escaped. so when using special characters it is ignored.

I have some text to echo, and escaping everything  manually just takes forever.

Does php have a similar function built in ?

thanks!

Comment: I think I might got the question wrong. Do you have to `echo` an escaped version of the string or do you have to escape chars in the string to have a correct string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Which are the characters do you have to escape?

You could use [**single quotes** *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single). The only characters that have to be escaped in such a string are `\` and `'`.

If you have a long string, also have a look at [**heredoc** *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Answer (score 3):

Since PHP 5.3, you can use [nowdoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). As opposed to heredoc, nowdoc does not expand variables inside it.

Answer (score 0):

There are various functions depending on what you want to escape.

If you are using a lot of double quotes, for example with html, you can wrap the string in single quotes to prevent having to escape.

```
$string = '<a href="#">no escape needed</a>';
```

The same goes the other way

```
$string = "I'd rather be gaming";
```

Then you have a couple of functions used mostly for escaping user input:

[addslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) that will escape quotes
[htmlspecialchars()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) will 'escape' html codes
[mysql_real_escape_string()](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for escaping mysql input