# PHP equivalent to python's triple-quotes - How to print bulk / lots of HTML within PHP without escaping

Tags: php, python, codeigniter, heredoc, language-comparisons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php string escaping like python’s “”“ ”“”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556178/php-string-escaping-like-pythons)

The triple-quotes in python escapes all quotes and newlines contained within. For example,

```
""" this
is all


just one string. I can even tell you "I like pi".
Notice that the single quotes are escaped - they don't end the string; and the newlines become part of the string
"""
```

Does anybody know if PHP has an equivalent to python's

```
""" <form><h1>PUT HTML HERE</h1> </form> """
enter code here
```

EDIT:
For those looking at this question in the future, I have answered it, here is an example:

`$heading = "Heading Gettizburgz";
                print <<< END
                <p><h1>$heading</h1> "in quotes" 'in single' 
                Four score and seven years ago<br/>
                our fathers set onto this continent<br/>
                (and so on ...)<br/>
                </p>
END;`

prints:

`Heading Gettizburgz
"in quotes" 'in single' Four score and seven years ago
our fathers set onto this continent
(and so on ...)`

Note one important thing, you must make sure that the very last `END` is to the far left (fist column) of your code without ANY spaces before it.

source: http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/php/php-here-document-heredoc-syntax-examples

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I think you didn't get the question because Markup swallowed all the newlines. Not the fault of the questioner at all.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Is this a "General Reference" question, or is it obscure enough that it might benefit others?  The answers posted so far seem fairly mundane.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I have searched for a similar question in the past (when I was learning PHP). I don't think this is a bad question. I think it has a place here on SO

Comment: Sorry guys, it looks like some of you saw what I just noticed -- in python you can have triple quotes and then put any HTML that you'd like within the three quotes as long as you close the string with """. I am looking for a way to do that within PHP because as it is I am always doing things like:
echo "<h1>" . $myVar . "</h1>" ; whereas in Python it is something like:
myVar2 = """ <h1> myVar </h1> """
print myVar2
Hope that helps, I'll try and be clearer next time. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [heredocs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) or nowdocs (see below heredocs).

**Heredoc**

```
$bar = <<<EOT
bar
EOT;
```

**Nowdoc**

```
$str = <<<'EOD'
Example of string
spanning multiple lines
using nowdoc syntax.
EOD;
```